# Shortcut closure syntax in case of [weak self]

Tags: swift, syntax, closures, swift5

Let's call some function, which has an escaping closure as a parameter:

```
someFunc(complition: {
    self.someAnotherFunc()
})
```

is equivalent to:

```
someFunc(complition: { [self] in
    someAnotherFunc()
})
```

is equivalent to:

```
someFunc(someAnotherFunc)
```

Was that correct?
I think that was correct.
`self` is capturing strongly above.

And what about case of [weak self]?
Is the only way we can write?:

```
someFunc(complition: { [weak self] in
    self?.someAnotherFunc()
})
```

Can't we somehow to write it like `someFunc(someAnotherFunc)`?

P.S. Okey, there is one more way to write it, I know:

```
someFunc { [weak self] in
    self?.someAnotherFunc()
}
```

But what about even more concise form?

Answer (score 2):

Currently (Swift 5.4) **Nothing else**

Actually, the default behavior of closures is to **NOT** capture `self` at all. But as soon as you reference `self` inside, it will create a strong reference to it.

<sub>There is an open discussion about it [here on swift.org](https://forums.swift.org/t/shouldnt-be-weak-self-the-default/29805)</sub>

Since you did not mention the code of your function, I can't be sure about your needs but generally, you may face some situations where you can ignore the self capture:

1. When you need a non-escaping closure
2. When the parent function is a class function (like the `UIView.animate...`)